# Integrating CAS and Symfony sfGuard?

Tags: symfony1, cas, sfguard

I'm trying to integrate CAS and sfDoctrineGuard. I want my login and logout to be controlled by CAS, which works perfectly with the [sfCASPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfCasPlugin).

However, I need to integrate this with the Users, Groups and Permissions from sfGuard. How can I do it?

I thought that I could "force" the login in sfGuard after logging with sfCas, but failed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way doing this with the default implementations of the sfCasPlugin and sfGuardPlugin. The only way would be to change a lot of the sfCasPlugin implemntation. So for Symfony 1.4 you will not be able to use a standard-plugin to implement this. This will get a lot easier to do with Symfony2.